# Adobe Flash Media Server - What are the application instances for?

Tags: flash

In using the Adobe Flash Media Server administrative tools, under `View Applications` I can create several instances of the same application.

Can anyone please enlighten me why I would need to start the same application more than once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

General suggestions based on other applications:

- Different settings per instance.
- Different connection parameters per instance.
- Logging.
- Isolation.